# Is it possible to determine the Date format an org uses?

Tags: apex, date

We have a package that we put into different orgs, and going in we don't know what date format they are using.  There is some parsing of dates from an external source.  Is there a way to determine in apex what format the org uses for it's dates?

EDIT:

Per running User works just as well for me.  I just need to know what format my date needs to be in at the time of execution.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the user settings (per user format) not at the org level...

Comment: @NathanWilliams Per User works just as good for me actually.

Comment: I think all you can do is format a distinctive date such as 22/11/3333 and parse it back into whatever date format pattern you want to use. There is no method I know of to get hold of e.g. the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: @KeithC I already know the format the date is coming in as.  When I try using the parse method though it errors depending on the locale that is setup.  I think I found a solution to my problem though.  Testing to see if I'm correct.

Comment: If you are parsing an incoming date of known format then yes you can pull it apart yourself and use Date.newInstance on the parts.

Comment: @KeithC I was actually trying to do that right now.  You can put that in an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Apex does not have a Date parse method where you can supply a format String but only [Data.parse](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_parse) that is tied to the locale the User is using.

So in a case like this where the external format is fixed you will need to break the parts down yourself and then pass the parts into [Date.newInstance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_newInstance).

Answer (score 0):

You can store the date and time format based on locale in custom setting. Then using a SOQL you can get the user locale and corresponding date / time formats from custom settings.

Then format the values based on below snippet

```
public static String formatDateTimeFields(String type, DateTime unformattedValue, String dateFormat, String timeFormat) {
    if(type == 'Date')
            return unformattedValue.format(dateFormat);        
        else if(type == 'Time')
            return unformattedValue.format(timeFormat);
        else if(type == 'DateTime')
            return unformattedValue.format(dateFormat +' '+ timeFormat);
}
```